# Any way to force JRE 7 or 8 to use JRE 6 AWT/Swing native focus mechanism?

Tags: java, windows, swing, focus, awt

As other questioners have [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10230006/focus-problems-with-jdk7-and-native-components), the Java AWT/Swing focus mechanism on Windows has [changed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-Desktop/html/awt.html#gdcqp) starting with Java 7.  While the documentation says "the mechanism is transparent for the user," it has broken some aspects of an application.

I don't want to get too bogged down right now in details of what has changed, or things that can be done to work around the problem; rather, I have one specific question.  Is there a way to force JRE 7 or 8 to use the pre-Java 7 native focus mechanism on Windows, either through a system property or an API?

Thanks for any insight that anyone can provide.

Comment: you could check the users mechine and in form them to update 
String version = System.getProperty("java.version");
if(version not equal good_version){
// open download page to java
}
or in windows force to run the jar file with an older jre:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047122/how-to-set-jar-application-to-use-java-6-instead-of-7

Comment: Thanks, that's not a bad idea.  But we don't have control over the JRE that's on the user's machine, and all other features work just fine with Java 7 and 8 except for one.  If we could force the newer JREs to exhibit the older focus behavior, that would be ideal, but it sounds like it might not be possible.